# How do i update the rendered data of a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making simple blog application, and i have a page for every individual post that is accessed this way:

```
http://localhost:3015/Post/post_id
```

And in the router i have set up the post component to render in this way:

```
<Route component={Post} path="/Post/post_id"></Route>
```

Then, in my post component i run the following code to make a call to the REST api im using:

```
componentDidMount(){
    let id = this.props.match.params.post_id

    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
        .then(res => {this.setState({ //res is short for responce
                post: res.data
            })
        })

    this.setState({
        id: id
    })
}
```

And this works for the first post - when i click on a post it takes me to that individual post but after that, even though the URL changes, it doesnt update the component. I checked the state through the developer tools on chrome and realized that it doesn't update the state either.

Im new to react, and decided to take on this small project before using it full time, so excuse me if i made a rookie mistake. After all i am a rookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Component will re-render only if some of his props or state changes, and if it's already mounted, componentDidMount it's not called again. So, you can try to call the rest api through your componentDidUpdate method (when the match params changes).

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.props.match.params.post_id != this.state.id) {
    // make the http call and update id, and post state
  }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Just so i don't accidentally ask a stupid question again:
If the component makes a single call to an API and will not make another call i should use componentWillMount, and if the component needs to make calls to an API to recieve data more then once throughout its life, i should make the call inside the componentDidUpdate hook. Right?

Comment: @SuperSimplePimpleDimple componentDidMount will call only when the component is inserted (mounted) on the DOM. So, if your call depends on some component parameter that will not change and it's available from the beginning of the React Component Lifecycle, then yes, you can call it from the didMount. If your call depends on some parameters or even the internal component state, then, you should make your call on componentDidUpdate. ComponentWillMount its considered legacy and it's recommended to not using it.